# Remote Desktop Username@IP vs. IP@Username Randomness

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, rdp, mstsc

Does anyone else find that when they open a saved connection in Remote Desktop it sometimes sets up the login as Username@IpAddress and other times (seemingly at random) sets it up as IpAddress@Username?

Does anyone know what the logic is behind the two / why this happens?

Comment: I removed the mtsc tag that was added by 'dove' because I didn't know what it was nor did Google.

Comment: sorry, typo mstsc is command for rdp in windows

Comment: @Unkwntech a little harsh down voting over that. if it's about the answer fine, no bother.

Answer (score 3):

I use Remote Desktop quite a bit, but I use the Domain\Username syntax instead of Username@Domain syntax, and I've never seen it get confused by that.

Comment: Same here. No problems with domain\username.

Answer (score -3):

If you rdp a lot, especially to several machines, then I would highly recommend you look at the free [royalts](http://www.code4ward.net/main/) tool.  I find it great to give context and it can remember passwords if that does not break your rules.  Easy to query who else is on remote box.

I've used this for a couple of years now and only been impressed.  It might require an update to your terminal services, but only a ms one.